# Как сделать условие like с массивом?

Tags: c#, sql

У меня есть условие по которому я проверяю элемент из бд с введёным  значением.

```
Select * from{sql} table1 where region like N’%’@region’%’
```

@region это переменная которую я сам ввожу в c# как вместо неё проверять массив таких значений?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `IN`, а не `LIKE`

`WHERE region in ('value1','value2',...)`

(Вариант работает на MySQL, не уверен что будет работать в других)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]